# Having a hard time with displaying information from my database

Tags: php

I'm just learning PHP and I followed the book to the last detail and when I go to the localhost web page that I created to pull information from the database nothing shows on the webpage. I've troubleshooted all night I've Google and read the book over and over to see what I missed. I'm posting the code that I wrote to see if someone can lead me in the right area to fix my problem.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pay Scale</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    table {
      background-color: #FCF;
    }

    th {
      width:150px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pay Scale</h1>

<form method= "post" action= "Payscale.php"
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<label> Search Category: 
<select name="category">
    <option value="Id">ID</option>
    <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
    <option value="Last_Name">Last_Name</option>
</select>
</label> <label>Search Criteria: 
<input type="text" name="criteria" />
</label> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){

    include('payconnect.php');

    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employee pay range WHERE $category = '$criteria'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die('error getting data');

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last_Name</th> <th>Pay_Range</th> </tr>";

    While($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $row['ID'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['First Name'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['Last_Name'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['Pay_Range'];
        echo "</td><tr>";
    }
    echo "<table>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to run your code through an HTML validator. You're missing a `>` in the line `<form method= "post" action= "Payscale.php"`.

Comment: You need to get an IDE with syntax highlighting (even this website has that feature). It'll make coding much easier.

Comment: MC Emperor I'm using notepad ++ and I've seen the highlighting on other people that uses it and I will find out how to get that to work for me. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks i alarmed alien and Stephen karanja

Comment: @DennardBeale if an answer has helped you, you should upvote it (click on the up arrow beside it) and you should also accept one answer by clicking the tick mark next to it--otherwise the question will be classified as unanswered. You should do the same with the other questions that you've asked on SO, too; it's a way of thanking the authors for taking the time to look at your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the html code for the page. The most obvious is that there is no closing `>` on your `form` tag, so the browser slurps up the next line, thinking that it is part of the `form` tag. Since that line sets the `$_POST['submitted']` variable that your PHP script is looking for, the value doesn't get set and the script never runs.

To correct the problem, just add a `>` to your `form` declaration:

```
<form method="post" action="Payscale.php">
```

There are also a few other problems in the HTML that could be fixed at the same time:

At the top of the page:

```
<html>
  <head>
```

A document should start with a `DOCTYPE` declaration so that the browser knows how to interpret the page. For HTML5, this is as simple as adding a line to the start of your file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

There is also an error in the table creation code:

```
    echo $row['Last_Name'];
    echo "</td><td>";        
    echo $row['Pay_Range'];
    echo "</td><tr>";        # A
}
echo "<table>";              # B
```

The lines marked A, and B create new elements--a table row, and a new table respectively. You should be closing the elements--i.e. using `</tr>` and `</table>`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your opening  tag is not closed (a minor syntactical error).

Try changing it from this:

```
<form method= "post" action= "Payscale.php"
```

to this:

```
<form method="post" action="Payscale.php">
```

and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Kind of a major syntactical error in this case, since it blocks the form from functioning!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it's working :**

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Pay Scale</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        table {
          background-color: #FCF;
        }

        th {
          width:150px;
          text-align: left;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Pay Scale</h1>

    <form method= "post" action="Payscale.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true"/>
    <label> Search Category: 
    <select name="category">
        <option value="Id">ID</option>
        <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
        <option value="Last_Name">Last_Name</option>
    </select>
    </label> <label>Search Criteria: 
    <input type="text" name="criteria" />
    </label> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitted"/>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Payscale.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){

    include('payconnect.php');

    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employee pay range WHERE $category = '$criteria'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die('error getting data');

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last_Name</th> <th>Pay_Range</th> </tr>";

    While($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $row['ID'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['First Name'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['Last_Name'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['Pay_Range'];
        echo "</td><tr>";
    }
    echo "<table>";
}
?>
```